# Facebook photo likes count

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the likes count of a facebook shared picture by photo id. I i paste this url to my browser i obtain a correct json result:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749/likes?summary=1
```

Any way this url doesn't work always, if i try to change the photo id with a photo that i have shared with my personal profile, it returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
 }
}
```

Why this behaviour? It's because the first is a page and the second is a user profile? For the second maybe i'm forced to login to facebook and obtain a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add at least an App Access Token if the photo is on a Page to get rid of the error message. If this is a User Photo, you need an User Access Token with `user_photos` permission.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo#Reading

> - To read a photo on a Page, use any valid access token
> - To read a photo for a User, you may read any photo with public privacy settings as long as the app accessing the photo has been granted the user_photos permission and you are using a valid access token